# Reducer state is not being updated with the new object [redux, redux-toolkit, normalize]

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, normalizr, redux-toolkit

There is a DeliveryManifestView component. It runs an effect which dispatches a thunk.

[image: useEffect - get data]

The thunk gets data from the api, then it is normalized with `normalizr`.

The `normalizedData` is passed to an action created by `redux-toolkit`.

[image: get data, normalize, and pass to reducer]

And the reducer returns the new object of the entity.

[image: return the entity]

It works perfectly on the first run. However if I go to another view then come back

the effect re-runs, the thunk is dispatched,

the data comes from the api,

the data passed to the reducer again and the reducer returns the new data,

but no changes happen in state, I still get the old state.

Here is the action diff from redux devtools

This is on the very first render
[image: first run]

After going back to another view and coming back

[image: data is not being changed here]

No diff in data reducer, even though a new data came from the api.

Comment: I've just run into this exact thing and am totally stumped. All my other reducers work as expected, and I have logged at every step, and it should all be fine. Seems like it must be a bug. Did you find a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that when normalizr gets an empty array it returns an `undefined` and so reducer returned `undefined` as well resulting in no changes. Here is the solution I came up with

[image]

giving a default value to the `deliveryPackages`.

Answer (score 0):

Ah - I had the same problem but turns out I was just being silly...

In my case it was the debugger. Not sure how i did it, but it was focused in on one particular part of the state, so my changes were happening but not showing in the diff. (Im using React Native Debugger)

As I say - can't figure out for the life of me how I turned it on, but I removed it by clicking on the names of other reducers that were displayed here by **Diff**:
[image]